# Kendo Grid - adding rows and then sort/change page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When you add a new item onto the Kendo Grid, it adds a row with input fields / editor templates. Before saving, when you sort or switch pages, it renders the added row onto the grid.

It doesn't make any ajax calls so it doesn't really save in the backend/database but my only issue is that it is rendered in the grid when it shouldn't (sorting should really just cancel any existing adds/edits).

Any fix or workaround on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround, is on the client page, add an event to the header clicks that will call cancel.

```
$("th.k-header").click(function(){
    $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').cancelChanges(); 
});
```

Just beware that this will make the grid lose ALL changes.

Another work around is just handle the data after clicking save changes, remove the empty rows either in the `parameterMap` of your datasource transport or on server side at the controller you can just ignore the invalid rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the **sort: onSortingFunctionName,** to your grid definition. Then you write your function to cancel changes.
check the possible events here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events

```
function onSortingFunctionName(arg) {
     $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').cancelChanges();
}
```